# ANTLRWorks not starting

Tags: antlr, osx-mountain-lion

I upgraded to Mountain Lion and when I start ANTLRWorks now, nothing happens. The logfile says:

```
8/22/12 6:43:24.881 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[185]: ([0x0-0x241c41a].org.antlr.works[65060]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 86
```

Edit: The runnable jar file still works, but the packaged application does not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behavior out of ALMWorks' JIRAClient.app 3.0.2 on Mountain Lion. Executable jar gets as far as the splash screen then crashes. I'm contacting support now.

Update: executable jar fails under JDK 7, but brings up the app successfully under JDK 6. This does not seem to have an effect, however, with regard to opening JIRAClient.app.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to have the Java update 2012-006. I was getting the same error after Mountain Lion update and this solved it.

- Almworks Jira: https://jira.almworks.com/browse/JCO-1183
- Apple download: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572